# .each no reconoce los elementos generados dinamicamente

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

el problema con el que me he topado es que requiero eliminar elementos por medio de checkbox sin embargo, lo que suelo hacer es eliminar lo elementos seleccionados y despues generar la tabla nuevamente con php y pasarla con json a jquery y ahi añadirla ala pagina remplazando con .html, pero al momento de querer eliminar nuevamente los elementos que selecciono no los reconoce... y pense que tal vez el usar .on para que funcionara pero al no funcionar me di cuenta que .on solo es para eventos y que .each que es el que uso para generar el arreglo de los checkbox es un metodo... asi que lo que necesito es alguna manera de usar algo parecido a each en elementos ya sean normales o generados dinamicamente por jquery

aqui les dejo el codigo que uso:

con este verifico que haya checkbox seleccionados y genero el mensaje de si estas seguro de eliminar con un modal.

```
$('#btn_delete').click(function(){
        $("#chk:checked").each(function() {
                chk_A.push($(this).val());
            }
        );
        if (chk_A.length != 0) 
        {
            $('#exampleModalLabel').html('<h3>Confirmar</h3>');
            $('.modal-body').html('<label><b>una vez realizada esta accion no se podra revertir...</b></label>');
            $('.modal-footer').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_delu">Entendido</button>');
            $("#open_model").modal('show');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('no se a seleccionado ningun usuario');
        }
    });
```

con este envio los datos con ajax una vez presionado que si esta seguro de eliminar:

```
$('body').on("click","#btn_delu",function(){
        var chk_B = new Array;
        var a = 1;
        var b = 1;
        $("#chk:checked").each(   
        function() {
                chk_B.push($(this).val());
            }
        );

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'inicio.php',
            dataType:"json",
            data:{ajax:a,elim_us:b,'array':JSON.stringify(chk_B)},
            success:function(data)
            {
                if (data == "Error") 
                {
                    alert('No se han podido eliminar los usuarios seleccionados');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#tbl_cont').html(data);
                    $("#open_model").modal('hide');
                    alert('se ha eliminado correctamente');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

y este es el php que se encarga de eliminar:

`````php
if (isset($_POST['elim_us'])) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        $data = json_decode($_POST['array']);
                        $ids = implode(',', $data);
                        $verificar = $obj->Ejecutar_Instruccion('DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id_us IN ('.$ids.')AND id_us !='.$_SESSION['id']);
                        $tabla_us = $obj->Ejecutar_Instruccion("select id_us, usuario_us, privilegio_us,aes_decrypt(contrasena_us, UNHEX(SHA2('tpn2019key',512))) as 'contrasena_us' from usuarios WHERE id_us !=".$_SESSION['id']);

                        foreach ($tabla_us as $renglon) 
                        {
                            $tabla_r .= '<tr class="centrar" ><td>'.$renglon['usuario_us'].'</td><td>'.$renglon['contrasena_us'].'</td><td>'.$renglon['privilegio_us'].'</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="chk[]" value="'.$renglon['id_us'].'" name="chk[]"></td></tr>';
                        }
                        echo json_encode($tabla_r);

                        /*echo json_encode($ids);*/
                    }
                    catch(Exception $e)
                    {
                        echo json_encode('Error');
                    }
                }
````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Trata de probar así

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_delete', function(){
        $("#chk:checked").each(function() {
                chk_A.push($(this).val());
            }
        );
        if (chk_A.length != 0) 
        {
            $('#exampleModalLabel').html('<h3>Confirmar</h3>');
            $('.modal-body').html('<label><b>una vez realizada esta accion no se podra revertir...</b></label>');
            $('.modal-footer').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_delu">Entendido</button>');
            $("#open_model").modal('show');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('no se a seleccionado ningun usuario');
        }
    });
```

Además deberías cambiar el segundo evento

```
$('body').on("click","#btn_delu",function(){}
```

a

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_delu', function(){}
```